# Disabling the clipboard history on Samsung devices

Tags: 9.0-pie, copy-paste, samsung-galaxy-note-9

Samsung Galaxy Note 9 running on Android 9 stores all old clipboard entries which requires me to manually delete it every time.

[image: "Clipboard" menu on text cursor pop-up]
[image: The content of the clipboard]

How can I opt-out of this "feature"?

Comment: AFAIK a clipboard with history is not part of the standard Android system. Therefore it has to be Samsung or app-specific.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After a long while and more serious privacy flops I had, I found a solution to this security breach of Samsung ([Credit](https://www.reddit.com/r/AndroidQuestions/comments/bxw0tm/is_it_possible_to_disable_the_clipboard_history/)).

1. Install `adb` on your computer ([manual](https://wiki.lineageos.org/adb_fastboot_guide.html#on-windows))
2. Setup adb access (e.g. USB Debugging) on your device ([manual](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#Enabling))
3. Launch `adb shell` and execute the following commands:

   - `pm uninstall --user 0 com.samsung.clipboardsaveservice`
   - `pm uninstall --user 0 com.samsung.android.clipboarduiservice`

Comment: Do you lost the Copy/Paste function after uninstalling samsung.clipboardsaveservice and samsung.android.clipboarduiservice while using Samsung Keyboard? BR

Comment: No. Only that nasty clipboard display.

Comment: "Only that nasty clipboard display" suggests a fix which is merely cosmetic. It would be good to know whether the two commands suggested above actually stop the OS from keeping a list of the stuff that was copied to the clipboard. Ideally, a command that could be run prior to the two `pm` commands that dumps the clipboard history could be repeated after the `pm` commands to show that the OS no longer has a notion of clipboard history.

Comment: "It would be good to know whether the two commands suggested above actually stop the OS from keeping a list of the stuff that was copied to the clipboard."

Now I have tested this. The OS not only keeps the list, but it also keeps adding to the list even if the above 2 applications are uninstalled.
(I installed them back and new entries where there.)
So unfortunately. This is not a solution. We need to find which application does the recording and maybe even where does it records them.

Comment: Does this solution work on rooted and non-rooted devices?

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket worked for me on a non rooted device.

Comment: To revert the uninstall, you can use `pm install-existing --user 0 <package name>`.  
For example `pm install-existing --user 0 com.samsung.clipboardsaveservice`

Answer (score -1):

Not tested because I am not rooted

ClipboardSaveService and ClipboardUI are made to keep copies of the Clipboard, and your system copy functionality will break if you disable/uninstall them (You need a ported AOSP version to let it only copy once and to make it be stored in the RAM not stored in the NAND)

You can use an Automation software (like Automate or Tasker) to delete "/data/Clipboard" files after you paste. (Yes this is the directory that Samsung store the files in it instead of RAM)