# Cannot disable the clipboard history feature on Samsung galaxy device

Tags: adb, samsung

Samsung devices have a clipboard history feature which is a big security risk for people who use a password manager.

I have tried disabling the `ClipboardSaveService` package as described in the thread ["Disabling the clipboard history on Samsung devices"](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/219057/disabling-the-clipboard-history-on-samsung-devices) but I am still able to see the clipboard history using the edge panel and the Samsung keyboard and I am not sure if disabling `clipboarduiservice` package will make any difference. Please tell me what other package do I need to disable so as to get rid of this non-sense clipboard history feature. Thanks.

Android Version: 12 (One UI Core 4.1)

Answer (score 1):

So I found out a workaround. **Please Backup everything before doing this!**

Install openboard -> make it your default keyboard -> uninstall com.samsung.clipboardsaveservice using adb -> uninstall Samsung keyboard using adb and you’re done!

After doing this, copying things to clipboard doesn’t populate the edge panel clipboard list, which probably indicates that clipboard history feature is not working

[OpenBoard on Play Store & FDroid](https://github.com/openboard-team/openboard)

Comment: From review: Can you please edit your answer to provide a link to openboard?